# PHP Code Doesn't Execute (new to php)

Tags: php

Okay so I am total noob in php since I recently started watching videos on php. So what I am trying to do is I have this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing PHP</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="action.php" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="first">
            <input type="text" name="second">
            <input type="submit" value="Submitto!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then I have my action.php file which has this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing PHP</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
            $first = $_POST['first'];
            $second = $_POST['second'];

            echo $first + $second;
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

However when I click on the submit button in my html file it sends me to a blank page. By the url I see that it has sent me to the right file but seems like the code doesn't execute.

PS: I tried searching on google but what I found was mostly stuff about apache not executing php which doesn't work for me since I try to run the files locally on my machine.

Comment: What are you using to run PHP locally?  It will not run in the client like JavaScript.  You need to setup a local server to run PHP locally on your machine.

Comment: I think this _IS_ about Apache not executing PHP. Try right-clicking the blank page and viewing the page source. If you see your PHP code, read some of the stuff you found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Blank Page Problem:**
First you have to install a local server on your machine like apache then you have to request this page from the local server to run PHP locally on your machine.

> [Here](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is the download page.

**For String concatenation:**
In php string concatenation operator is `.` sign not the `+` sign,so you have to use `.` operator instead of `+` operator.

```
echo $first . $second;
```

action.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing PHP</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
            $first = $_POST['first'];
            $second = $_POST['second'];

            echo $first . $second;
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

For more knowledge about String Operators read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: String concatenation is not an issue, it can not result in empty page. And if he is trying to add two numbers, then "+" will work, while "." will produce wrong result.

Comment: Yes string concatenation is not the issue here but i thought he is trying to add two string in his code that's why i  give him a hint of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (I just actually checked it), but you still need a web server, even if you run your code locally.

Recent versions of php include the built-in webserver, so first try this (in the folder where your html and php files are placed):

```
php -S localhost:8888
```

Then open http://localhost:8888/your.html in the browser.

If your php is too old (older than 5.4.0), you will need to setup apache or ngnix to be able to run you php code.